# ELKI Default parameter settings for (clustering) algorithms

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, elki

I'm working on a research project that involves showing visually the result of many clustering results. I saw that the clustering classes always bring their own parameterizer static classes.

Is it somehow possible to instantiate all elki algorithms with predefined parameter settings?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Parameterization API to instantiate and get default values for those parameters, that have default values.

https://elki-project.github.io/howto/java_api#ParameterizationAPI

The current development version has a new "fluent" API, called `ELKIBuilder`.

Most unit tests have been rewritten to use this, e.g., [AGNESTest](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/9908f56f14ec76912745369edb68c07c4339eae0/elki-clustering/src/test/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/hierarchical/AGNESTest.java)

```
Clustering<?> clustering = new ELKIBuilder<>(CutDendrogramByNumberOfClusters.class) //
        .with(CutDendrogramByNumberOfClusters.Parameterizer.MINCLUSTERS_ID, 3) //
        .with(AbstractAlgorithm.ALGORITHM_ID, AGNES.class) //
        .with(AGNES.Parameterizer.LINKAGE_ID, SingleLinkage.class) //
        .build().run(db);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I found the elkibuilder before, but I need it even a little more "low level". All algorithms have a dedicated set of parameters that clearly influence its performance (obviously). As I have seen from the code, the Elkibuilder requests the Parameterizer who checks the minimum Parameterization "requirements" (ClassGenericUtils.parameterizeOrAbort()).Please correct me if that is wrong. What I need is to use automatically the minimum/default parameters for most parameters, so that i just need to set e.g. K for partition based methods or eps for density based methods.

Comment: So you want to access the parameter constraints? See `TrackParameters`, that will give you a list of all parameters in the context, and their constraints. From the constraints you can get the minimum value (this was intended for UI purposes, where you could, e.g., have a spinner control for the k-means k parameter that cannot go below 1).